# Delegate on a function with an argument being a pointer on a native type

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm working in an application mixing C# and C++-CLI, and I'm not very familiar with the syntax C++-CLI.

In this application, I have a method to get a position, defined in a C++-CLI module:

```
public ref class MyBigClass
{
    MyClassA m_myobject;
    // plenty of things
    void GetPosition(double &dPosX, double &dPosY);
};
```

Now, in another C# module, I want to create a delegate with this method. I've tried the following syntax:

```
public delegate void OnGetPositionHandler(ref double X, ref double X);
public class MyClassA
{
    //...
    public event OnGetPositionHandler OnGetPosition;
}
```

In a second C++-CLI file, I create the delegate like this:

```
m_myobject->OnGetPosition += gcnew OnGetPositionHandler(this, &MyBigClass::GetMotionPos);
```

But I get a compilation error (C3352), saying that "the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (double %,double %)'."

I've tried to change the definition of my delegate, without any success.

What is the correct syntax to make a delegate on such a method?

Comment: Try exposing the delegate from C++/CLI and see what is expected on the C# side.

Comment: @HansPassant It works! Thanks, post it as an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does not match the delegate type 'void (double %,double %)`

The error message gives you a huge hint, you must declare the arguments with `%` instead of `&` so they are passed as a managed pointer instead of a native pointer.  Fix:

```
   void GetPosition(double% dPosX, double% dPosY);
```

The next problem you'd typically run into is that your native C++ code would require a native pointer.  You can't convert the managed pointer to the native pointer, the compiler stops you from shooting your leg off.  The kind of fatal wound incurred when the garbage collector moves the *double* when it compacts the heap and the native code writes back to where the double was once located.  Corrupting the GC heap when doing so.

Fixing that requires providing the native code with a stable address for the value.  Boilerplate is:

```
void MyBigClass::GetPosition(double% dPosX, double% dPosY) {
   double x, y;
   m_myobject->GetPosition(&x, &y);
   dPosX = x;
   dPosY = y;
}
```

Otherwise also the core reason that the compiler will typically insist that you declare `m_myobject` as a MyClass* instead of MyClass.  Allocate in the constructor, destroy in the destructor *and* finalizer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, perfect answer for me.